# "... His entreaties which are hearkened/hearkened unto by God"

Tags: archaicisms, antiquated

The verb ***to hearken*** is an archaic verb which I need to use for my translation into KJV Bible style of English.

I see it used with the prepositions ***to*** and ***unto*** in the KJV, but never in this structure:

> 1. His entreaties, (which are) ***hearkened by*** God, would always prevail.

This was my first version, but while elaborating the text with an English colleague, she pointed out to me the need of the preposition ***unto*** after ***hearkened***. So the sentence would look like this:

> 2. His entreaties, (which are) ***hearkened unto by*** God, would always prevail.

I know this is how verbs with prepositions are used in such cases, she is most probably right, but I still prefer the feel of sentence 1. Sentence 2 seems heavier and less successful, perhaps because of the juxtaposition of two prepositions (*unto by*).

The Dictionaries on the web are rather "stingy" on this verb ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=hearken%20meaning&safe=strict&rlz=1C1CHBF_enGB888GB888&sxsrf=ALeKk01rP2kgGFKbK141j0iwYQANAF324A%3A1623169231857&ei=z5i_YK7zM5KmUP-jjeAJ&oq=hearken&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIECCMQJzIECAAQQzIFCAAQkQIyBQgAEJECMgUIABCRAjIECAAQQzICCAAyAgguMgQIABBDMgIIADoICAAQsQMQgwE6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOgUIABCxA1CkryxY_rYsYI7CLGgAcAJ4AIABvwKIAbQJkgEHMS42LjAuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=gws-wizhttps://www.google.com/search?q=hearken%20meaning&safe=strict&rlz=1C1CHBF_enGB888GB888&sxsrf=ALeKk01rP2kgGFKbK141j0iwYQANAF324A%3A1623169231857&ei=z5i_YK7zM5KmUP-jjeAJ&oq=hearken&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIECCMQJzIECAAQQzIFCAAQkQIyBQgAEJECMgUIABCRAjIECAAQQzICCAAyAgguMgQIABBDMgIIADoICAAQsQMQgwE6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOgUIABCxA1CkryxY_rYsYI7CLGgAcAJ4AIABvwKIAbQJkgEHMS42LjAuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hearken), [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hearken)).

The [American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hearken) gives a bit more information but the examples do not help with my question:

> Usage Note: Traditionally, hearken means "to listen." The word has an
> archaic and formal air today, in part stemming from its extensive use
> in the King James Bible (as in Mark 7:14 "*Hearken unto me, every one
> of you*") and in traditional storytelling. In contemporary usage,
> hearken is more often used where one might expect hark, no doubt
> because of sound similarity: *The movie hearkens back to the sci-fi
> films of the 1950s*. The Usage Panel has mixed feelings about this. In
> our 2009 survey, just 48 percent accepted this example.

Is sentence 2 the only correct one? Is my colleague correct in saying that sentence 1 is incomplete?

Comment: As you know, the word ***hearken*** is hopelessly dated, particularly as the past tense ***hearkened*** in a passive construction, so I'd advise you to avoid it anyway (you can just use ***heard*** or ***listened to*** today). But if you *insist* on using it, note that preposition-wise, it's similar to ***listen*** (which requires ***to*** between the past tense verb and ***by** [listener]*, in contexts like *The song was **listened to by** the audience*).

Comment: ...see [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hearkened+by%2Chearkened+to+by%2Chearkened+unto+by&year_start=1700&year_end=1900&corpus=26&smoothing=3) comparing 1: ***hearkened by***, 2: ***hearkened to by***, 3: ***hearkened unto by***. From which you'll see that the first version (without ***un/to***) was always exceptionally rare.

Comment: Good search! I gave up on Ngram after [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were+hearkened+unto+by%2C+were+hearkened+by&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=).

Comment: It is a text that needs to look and sound outdated or antiquated or whatever you call it. I am afraid I am stuck with "hearken" which is most used for God listening to man in the KJV. Actually, "listen" is only used once in the whole of the KJV Bible, I was amazed to find. "Hear" is better, but does seem a bit too common for the context. Yet, I am keeping it as an option, in case everything fails with "hearken".

Comment: Understood. That's why my NGram link was for the two centuries before 1900, rather than more recent stuff. But even though you might not want actually *use* the word "listen", you can still take it as a guide to preposition syntax in respect of "hearken".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, that was a very good point and I definitely got it. The reason I asked this question was because I kind of knew my colleague was right, but out of nostalgia for sentence 1 that strangely sounded better, I hoped I could find some grounds to finally use it nevertheless. So my choice now is between _**hearkened unto by**_ and _**heard by**_. Thing is, my text needs to also sound poetic, imagine.

Comment: I think the passive construction is always going to be a bit awkward here, regardless of which *specific* verb you use. But you might want to consider less "quaint" alternatives such as ***heed, attend, note, mark***.

Comment: Why would you want to say *which are hearkened unto by God* rather than *which God hearkens to* or *to which God hearkens*? That's like saying *the abyss, which was fallen into by the climbers*, rather than *the abyss, which the climbers fell into* or *the abyss, into which the climbers fell* — it's very awkward, and I suspect it would have been very awkward even when they wrote the King James Bible.

Comment: @PeterShor: I agree it is awkward.But I need this text to sound both antiquated and poetic. In the particular sentence, I need a verb like **hearken** (or one of its synonyms) to be used as an adjectival participle. Your proposition is good, but it lacks the poetic rhythm I need. You don't want a poem to sound like normal language. FF's alternative of **heed** gave me a solution that I might just use: _**entreaties heeded by God**_ is very close to what I need. PS: In the KJV, **hearken** is never used in the passive. Guess I was trying to be more antiquated than the KJV!

Comment: @fev: You don't want poetic language to sound so awkward that even the translators of the King James Bible didn't use it, either. You're right — what you need here is a transitive verb, like *heeded* or *heard*. (After searching a little, I'd use *heard*; *heed* seems to always be a noun in the King James Bible, as in *take heed* or *give heed*.)

Comment: @PeterShor: Exactly, we agree on **heed**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hearken* is usually a prepositional verb in that it most frequently appears (appeared) in a construction with an oblique object (one contained in a prepositional phrase) when there was an object present.

The [HANSARD](https://www.english-corpora.org/hansard/) corpus (British Parliament) has three examples in the passive.

> I can only hope that the words of the Foreign Secretary will be
> **hearkened to** by nations beyond the seas (1936)
>
> Members might ask themselves how that plea has been **hearkened to** by
> the Tories of Northern Ireland who comprise about two-thirds of the
> people there (1920)
>
> I hope that my plea will be **hearkened to** by the noble Lords opposite,
> and that nothing will be done this afternoon to delay getting this
> Bill on to the Statute Book (1966)

[COHA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) (Corpus of Historical American English) yielded one example in the passive:

> he was scarcely **hearkened to** at all by his contemporaries, who looked
> upon him as merely an ingenious sort of madman (The Works of Edgar
> Allan Poe — Volume 4, 1855)

The [EEBO](https://www.english-corpora.org/eebo/) corpus (Early English Books Online) has quite a few uses in the passive with *unto* or *to*. A sample:

> Wherfore that you may as a fresh be put in minde hereof, and the
> exhortations of the apostles **hearkened unto** by you, i thinke fit in
> this place to set before you some of them (Proctor, Thomas, fl. 1621.)
>
> it were too presumptuous a thought in me to expect, that any advise of
> mine should be **hearkened unto** by you who have so many learned and
> renowned doctors to consult upon all occasions (Gatford, Lionel, d.
> 1665.)
>
> their advice scarse at all **hearkened unto** by the king, but other
> counsels of unknowne persons preferred before them (May, Thomas,
> 1595-1650.)
>
> a meer forgery, yet gladly **hearkened unto** by those that desired to be
> rid of them (Spottiswood, John, 1565-1639. | Duppa, Brian, 1588-1662.)
>
> a motion had been made a little before, for appointing a commissioner
> or Deputie in the Kingdome, which was **hearkened unto** by the king as
> that which would ease him of many vexations (Spottiswood, John,
> 1565-1639. | Duppa, Brian, 1588-1662.)
>
> that their arguments are not **hearkened vnto** but by people of a weake
> braine (1629, Sarpi, Paolo, 1552-1623. | Brent, Nathaniel, Sir, 1573?-1652.)

> let it be seriously **hearkened to** by all the ministers of christ
> (Brinsley, John, 1600-1665.)
>
> this motion was not **hearkened to** by men grown fierce (Clarke, Samuel,
> 1599-1682. Gun-powder treason. 1671)
>
> the affairs of the league seemed not to be **hearkened to** by him with
> the same inclination wherewith his predecessors had imbraced them
> (1678, Davila, Arrigo Caterino, 1576-1631. | Aylesbury, William,
> 1615-1656. | Cotterell, Charles, Sir, d. 1701. | L'Estrange, Roger,
> Sir, 1616-1704.)
>
> about two years before this there appear'd in cromwel's time a
> prophetess, much fam'd for her dreams and visions, and **hearkened to** by
> many (Behemoth, or, An epitome of the civil wars of England, from 1640
> to 1660 by Thomas Hobbes)

*Thereunto* was apparently also a choice:

> it hath had this blissing to thousands and ten thousand thousands that
> haue **hearkened thereunto** (Babington, Gervase, 1550-1610.)
>
> the Bishoppe promised his best diligence, and accordingly after his
> returne, laboured therein with king henry, who most gladly **hearkened**
> **thereunto** (Speed, John, 1552?-1629.)
>
> who hath considered of his word, and **hearkened thereunto**? (1638)

A few examples exist with *hearken* taking an object, but I couldn't find any examples in the passive without a preposition.

> moses excuseth himselfe unto the lord, saying, they would not beleave
> him nor **hearken** him, alledging, that the lord had not appeared unto
> him (Goodwin, John, 1594?-1665.)
>
> he shall crie to Iesus christ at his last daie, and scarcely woll he
> **hearken** him (1687)
>
> sim sure: let vs **hearken** them ( Udall, Nicholas, 1505-1556.)
>
> i see now from afarre what thou purposest, algates i desire yet to
> **hearken** it of thee more plainly (1687)
>
> thou shalt holly with all thy wit Doe thine entent to **hearken** it: yes
> sir (1687)

So in answer to your question, it seems that both the use with and without a preposition are (were) possible, the prepositional version being apparently the more common.

Comment: Would be really grateful if you could format your answer so that the occurrences of **hearkened** be more visible. I hope it is not too much for you.

Comment: @fev No trouble at all.

Comment: Thank you, it really helps me orient myself and shift to another choice. And the Corpuses you provided are very helpful. I would like to use them in the future. I will search them online.

Comment: I have added links to the Corpuses you've provided. I thought it would be useful for others, too. Hope that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple case of distinguishing between *transitive* and *intransitive* verbs.

Used transitively, *hearken* warrants a direct object, and that's how your first version reads (in the passive voice, of course.)

Here's how M-W defines *hearken* transitively:

> archaic : to give heed to : HEAR

*The active voice* version would read:

> His entreaties, which God hearkens, would always prevail.

But the verb *hearken* (like most other verbs) could be used intransitively as well, and that's where the *fancy-sounding* preposition *unto* (which is actually a stylized version of the modest *to*) comes into play— because intransitive verbs, by definition, don't take a direct object.

And that's why the active voice of your second version would read:

> His entreaties, which God hearkens unto/to, would always prevail.

But as you have mentioned in the question itself— and as AHD concurs— this latter version has a rather formal and archaic air.

And as regards who is "more" correct— you or your friend— the answer is neither, because it is simply a case of using a verb in its two different avatars.

*Sentence 2 seems heavier and less successful, perhaps because of the juxtaposition of two prepositions (unto by).*

I take this misgiving with a pinch of salt: it is par for the course in English to see such constructions. A phrasal verb (Verb+Preposition combo), for instance, when passivized would almost always take after it *another preposition.*

Comment: Not all verbs can be used transitively. 'Snore' and 'listen' are two common examples.  I've never seen _hearken_ used transitively. You need to add an attributed reference endorsing a transitive usage. // It's better to consider _usages_, not _verbs_, as transitive/intransitive. It's unhelpful to say to someone '_Paint_ is an intransitive verb, you know.'

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Certainly not all verbs, but _hearken_ is not one of them. And _Merriam-Webster_ concurs.

Comment: DW256 got the support in first, and the examples given suggest the transitive usage was rare even in EME.

Comment: +1 for pointing to the transitive use of **hearken**, however rare it may be. It's good to know it exists.